# Error "is property but is used like type"

Tags: c#

I am getting error `"Model.Password is property but is used like type"`.

What i am trying to do is basically create class constructor to assign default value to `Password` property of class `NewUser`.

I'm quite new to C# so appreciate if i can be guided what i'm doing wrong here and how to correct it?

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace Model
{
    public class NewUser
    {
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public class NewUser()
        {
        Password = "Admin123";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `class` keyword is not expected in the constructor.

Comment: @ leppie, thanks you for your reply. I am clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructors do not have a return type. Change your code to this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace Model
{
    public class NewUser
    {
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public NewUser()
        {
            Password = "Admin123";
        }
    }
}
```

When you define a constructor, you just declare the visibility (`public`, `protected`, or `private`) and then the name of the class (`NewUser` in this case), then optional parameters. In your case, you don't look like you want any. But you could do this too:

```
public NewUser(string password)
{
    Password = password;
}
```

Then instantiate it like this:

```
var newUser = new NewUser("Admin123");
```

And its okay to have both constructors, if you want. That way they can implicitly specify a password, or if they don't specify one, default it to something (such as `Admin123`)

Comment: thanks you for your explanation. I am quite clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Remove class from the Ctor. You don't return the type from the constructor, you just set construsctor access modifier.

```
namespace Model
{
    public class NewUser
    {
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public NewUser()
        {
            Password = "Admin123";
        }
    }
}
```